# How do i write zod schema for a deeply nested object

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, api, zod

I have the following data:

```json
{
  "2022-06-01": {
    "09:00am": {
      "time_table_id": 1,
      "job_id": 4,
      "start_working_time": "09:00am",
      "end_working_time": "09:00pm",
      "work_duration": "12:00:00",
      "merchant_name": "Brands Outlet @ The Starling",
      "address2": "Jalan SS 21/37, Damansara Utama",
      "job_name": "Pro hero",
      "job_application_status": "Hired"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my schema but it is giving me a zod error.

```js
const apiScheme = z.object({
  Date: z.object({
    Time: z.object({
      date: z.string(),
      time_table_id: z.number().nullable(),
      job_id: z.number(),
      start_working_time: z.string(),
      end_working_time: z.string(),
      // work_duration: z.string(),
      // merchant_name: z.string(),
      // address2: z.string(),
      job_name: z.string(),
      job_application_status: z.string(),
    }),
  }),
});

// -- snip -- (React code):

const data = useMemo(() => {
  if (responseData) {
    const parseData = apiScheme.parse(responseData);
    //    error here ~~~~~~~~~~-^
    if (parseData) {
      return parseData;
    }
  }
  return null;
}, [responseData]);
```

Comment: Do you have any specifics on the error. I put in that schema  and apiScheme.parse({}) gave me no errors.

Answer (score 8):

I think your problem is that you're using the `z.object` type when you actually want to be using `z.record`.

```js
const apiSchema = z.record(
  z.string(), // Key type for the outer record
  z.record(
    z.string(), // Key type for the second level record
    z.object({
      time_table_id: z.number().nullable(),
      job_id: z.number(),
      start_working_time: z.string(),
      end_working_time: z.string(),
      work_duration: z.string(),
      merchant_name: z.string(),
      address2: z.string(),
      job_name: z.string(),
      job_application_status: z.string()
    }),
  ),
);
```

`z.object` is used in cases like the schema for the inner most object, where all of the field names are known and will remain the same. `z.record` is used when you have a type like [TypeScript's Record type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) which is just an object that is indexable but the actual keys of the object are not known at compile time.

---

**Small Aside**: If you know at compile time that the values are always going to be the same date and time, you could instead write the schema like:

```js
z.object({
  "2022-06-01": z.object({
     "09:00am": z.object({ /* ... */ }),
  },
});
```

but I am assuming that the "Date" and "Time" indexes are not known at compile time. A schema like the one above should parse the exact data shape in your example as well (but would fail if either of the dates or times were different).